# "Ordered every time", "have ordered every time" or "order every time"

Tags: tense

There is a restaurant where you always ordered Caesar salad before. But one day you decide to have something else. When the waitress asks you if you want Caesar salad again before you say anything, which sentence is the most acceptable as a reply?

> I know I **ordered** Caesar salad every time, but today I want something
> else.
>
> I know I **have ordered** Caesar salad every time, but today I want
> something else.
>
> I know I **order** Caesar salad every time, but today I want something
> else.

Comment: They're all syntactically valid, but the last one is the most "natural". Note that *actually*, none of your exact alternatives are very likely compared to *I [always / usually] order Caesar salad, but today...* (don't bother with the Perfect at all) OR ***I've** always **ordered** Caesar salad before, but today...* (where *some* people might say the Perfect adds "emphasis" to the reference to the past, in which case arguably it works better with ***always*** than ***usually***).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best variant is probably:

"I usually order Caesar salad, but today I'd like to try something else."

Yes, you could preface that with "I know (that)..." if you prefer.

Examining the original proposed sentences, number 3 is the most natural,  using the present tense.  The next choice is present perfect "I've always ordered, but...". Finally, the past tense (simply the word "ordered") doesn't fit well, because you are in the restaurant at the moment, and you are still placing orders, so the action is not strictly past tense, it's also connected to the present (which is what Present Perfect communicates).